# asp.net mail message can not do replytolist.add

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailmessage

I have a page in which i am sending out an email blast. The page works and sends out an email. However, when i a try to add email addresses to include as replyto recipients i am getting this error:

```
'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' does not contain a definition for 'ReplyToList' and no extension method 'ReplyToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

i am using this code:

mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("abc@abc.com");

this works for 
                    mailMessage.CC.Add("abc@abc.com");mailMessage.bcc.Add("abc@abc.com");
etc.

Thank you

Comment: What framework version are you targetting?

Comment: .net framework 3.5

Answer (score 1):

As your compiler is trying to tell you, no such property exists.

If you look in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist), you'll see it was added in .Net 4.0.

Earlier versions use the [`ReplyTo` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replyto) instead.

Comment: then i get  this error instead: 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @johnsmith: Read the documentation.  That isn't a list.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance  - how would i then set it?  i can not do mailmessage.replyto=""

Comment: Read the error message or documentation.  You need to set it to a `MailAddress` instance.

Comment: thank you.
mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("123@gmail.com");

Comment: how to add two reply to email addresses?

Comment: @johnsmith: That's only supported by .Net 4.